# OnClick function using Vite+Blade Laravel

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, vite

I have a new laravel application, where I am using Vite

I have already included my js files in vite.config and also in the head of my html

```
@vite(['resources/js/services/live.js'])
```

however, when I try to use a button with the onclick function, it does not find any of my functions.

For example, let's say this is my js file "resources/js/services/live.js"

```js
var Print = function () { alert('Test'); };
```

Now in my html, where I have already included my js using vite, I want to do the following

```html
<input type="button" onclick="Print()"
```

But when I click the button, js debugger says "Print is undefined"

I have already tried with function `Print()`, `export function`, but the same result.

Is there something that I am missing using vite?

I have tried exporting the function, creating a variable to access, creating a class, but none looks to work

Comment: how about using addEventListener ?

Comment: **Round 1:** Trying placing the function inside the blade file; and see it is working.

**Round 2:** View page source and figure out if the js file included correctly and has you code for the function.

Comment: Inserting the function inside the blade it works, but I prefer to have it in another file
What I have found that works right now is: on the js file to the function add `window.<functionName>`